# nagios - nsclient - nsca - host_check message

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I’ve configured some clients to use the nsca to send data to Nagios since I’m not able to connect from server to the client. I was able to achieve like everything I wanted, but one last thing is not exactly how I would like.

The host check / status information is not appending a message I want. This is my nsclient.ini conf:

```
[/settings/scheduler/schedules]
host_check = Check_OK
;host_check = Check_OK “OK”
```

And in the nagios server I see these messages:

> Jun 30 06:52:02 localhost nagios: EXTERNAL COMMAND:
> PROCESS_HOST_CHECK_RESULT;client;0;No message Jun 30 06:57:16
> localhost nagios: EXTERNAL COMMAND:
> PROCESS_HOST_CHECK_RESULT;client;0;No message Jun 30 07:02:31
> localhost nagios: EXTERNAL COMMAND:
> PROCESS_HOST_CHECK_RESULT;client;0;No message Jun 30 07:11:17
> localhost nagios: EXTERNAL COMMAND:
> PROCESS_HOST_CHECK_RESULT;client;3;Invalid command line: unrecognised
> option 'OK' Jun 30 07:11:17 localhost nagios: Error: External command
> failed -> PROCESS_HOST_CHECK_RESULT;client;3;Invalid command line:
> unrecognised option 'OK' Jun 30 07:11:17 localhost nagios: External
> command [1656573077] PROCESS_HOST_CHECK_RESULT;client;3;Invalid
> command line: unrecognised option 'OK' returned error Command failed

So, when I use the “OK” I get that 3 invalid command line: unrecognised option ‘OK’ and when I don’t use any message I got that 0 No message.

Any thought what I’m doing wrong here?
nsclient version = NSCP-0.5.2.35-x64

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It gave me some hard time to figure out but after deciding to check the documentation I tried couple other stuff and ended up with this way to get that message passed along:

```
host_check = check_ok message=OK
```

This way Nagios UI I can see the Status Information for the host as "OK" and how I was expecting.